# For all positive integers $n$ , find the remainder of the division of $\frac{(7n)!}{7^n×n!}$ by $7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For all positive integers $n$ , find the remainder of the division of $\frac{(7n)!}{7^n×n!}$ by $7$
I tried to simplify the expression $\frac{(7n)!}{7^n×n!}=\frac{7n×...×(n+1)}{7^n}$ but it didn't help much

Comment: Well, by Legendre's formula, $$\nu_7((7n)!)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lfloor \frac{7n}{7^i}\rfloor=n+\lfloor n/7\rfloor+\lfloor n/49\rfloor+\cdots=\nu_7(7^n\cdot n!)$$ So the answer isn't $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the fact that $\frac{(7(n + 1))!}{7^{n + 1} (n + 1)!} = \frac{(7n)!}{7^n n!} \frac{\prod\limits_{i = 7n + 1}^{7n + 7} i}{7(n + 1)} = \frac{(7n)!}{7^n n!} \prod\limits_{i = 7n + 1}^{7n + 6} i$.

Let $a_n \in \mathbb{Z}_7$ be the reduction of $\frac{(7n)!}{7^n (n + 1)}$ mod 7. Then we see that $a_0 = 1$ and $a_{n + 1} = a_n \prod\limits_{i = 1}^6 i$. Thus, we see that $a_n = (\prod\limits_{i = 1}^6 i)^n$ by induction.

Edit: now by Wilson's Theorem, $\prod\limits_{i = 1}^6 i = (i - 1)! \equiv -1 \mod 7$, since $7$ is a prime.

Therefore, we have $a_n = (-1)^n$.

Thus, we see that when $n$ is even, $a_n = 1$ and thus the remainder is 1. When $n$ is odd, we see that $a_n = -1 = 6$, and thus the remainder is 6.

Comment: Your last part wasn't that clear for me :/, the induction and the fact that the remainder is $(-1)^|\mathbb{F}|$ can you please make it simpler for me?

Comment: @snowprincess Consider a finite field $\mathbb{F}$. Note that for all units $u \in \mathbb{F}^\times$, we have $u^{|\mathbb{F}| - 1} = 1$. Therefore, the roots of the polynomial $x^{|\mathbb{F}| - 1} - 1$ are exactly the units of $\mathbb{F}$, and so we can write $x^{|\mathbb{F}| - 1} - 1 = \prod\limits_{u \in \mathbb{F}^\times} x - u$. Evaluating both polynomials at $0$ gives us $-1 = \prod\limits_{u \in \mathbb{F}^\times} -u = (-1)^{|\mathbb{F}| - 1} \prod\limits_{u \in \mathbb{F}} u$, which gives us that $\prod\limits_{u \in \mathbb{F}^\times} u = (-1)^{|\mathbb{F}|}$.

Comment: A simpler way to express the end, $a_n\equiv (-1)^n\pmod{7}$ since $1\cdot 2\cdots 6\equiv -1\pmod{7}$.

Comment: @TheBestMagician This is exactly what I said. Except that I proved it in much broader generality, so if you replaced 7 with any odd prime, you'd get the same answer.

Comment: @MarkSaving Yes, I just wanted to put it in terms that avoided the word "field". Also, this is just Wilson's theorem ($(p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod{p}$)

Comment: @TheBestMagician I had forgotten this was a well-known theorem, which was why I rederived it.